# No house number with Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API (v3). It is used to look up places with the autocomplete function.

When I search for 'De Koffiebrandery', the result I get is almost complete. The only thing that is missing, is the house number.

When I look for 'De Koffiebrandery' in Google I can see that the house number is present in the result.

How can I get the Google Maps API autocomplete to return the house number as well?

Hopefully someone can help me out with this!

Comment: What result do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the 'Street Number' is there. It is '40'. The other number you see is the postal-code (5222 BH). You can console the response. Here's the response on my end.

[image]

Comment: Aha, thanks! I think it has to do with the tool I'm using to pick the location. It uses the Google Maps API, but apparently doesn't return the Street Number. I'll look into that!